Computing a seemingly "$i$th" order integral
I recently learned about the cauchy repeated integration formula, which is stated as follows
$$\int_{a}^{t}f(x)\hspace{1mm}dx^n = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_{a}^{t}(t-x)^{n-1}f(x)dx$$
I decided to have some fun and tried computing a seemingly $\iota$  order integral of a function
Plugging in $i$ to the above function we get
$$\int_{a}^{t}f(x)\hspace{1mm}dx^i = \frac{1}{\Gamma(i)}\int_{a}^{t}(t-x)^{i-1}f(x)dx$$
The first step in computing this for me is to find a closed form for $\Gamma(i)$, this is the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{i - 1}e^{-t}dt$$
I tried using integration by parts for this integral however it resulted in computing a similar derivative again and again, I also tried using, some substitutions however it did not seem to work.
I would appreciate any help on how to form a closed form for this, or is this even integrable, would love to solve this and maybe find the $i$ order integral for some simple function like say $x^2$.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Is $\iota$ the complex $i$?

Yeah thats how iota shows up on mathjax on this website i guess

$\Gamma(i)$ has a known value, but not sure if it has a closed form. See here : https://oeis.org/A212877, https://oeis.org/A212878.

Seems like an answer however this integral seems to good to not be computed

There is no real use for this. Even for real $n$ there exists no closed form for most functions aka you just use special functions. E.g. for the fractional integral of $f(x)=e^{a x}$ it's the $E_t$-function aka even if you find a closed form for $\Gamma\left( i \right)$ that will not help (for most functions).

@YvesDaoust Oh kay ill edit it

@KevinDietrich Nice point, however i do not see it having a use either just something fun i wanted to do !

@StudyJee, $|\Gamma(i)|$ has a closed form of $\frac{\pi}{sinh(\pi)}$. As far as I know, $\Gamma(i)$ doesn't have a closed form.

@Srini I think you mean $|\Gamma(i)|^2=\frac{\pi}{\sinh\pi}$.

Sorry, yes. What you said, @J.G.

Why cant we find $\Gamma(i)$, could you link a derivation for $|\Gamma(i)|^2 = \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}$ so i could get some inspiration

Computing $\Gamma (i)$ isn't that easy; also check out the wikipedia article on the gamma function, it has a proof for that identity if I remember correctly

There is no closed form solution to $\Gamma(i)$. While we don't know of a closed form solution we have evaluated it numerically to be $-0.15495 - 0.498016i$.
If you want to compute the Gamma function with complex arguments by hand you can look into Sterling approximations. Of course, any CAS, such as Mathematica, can also be used.
